# Is it okay for Work to constantly place me in a high playing job position and be paid the same lower salary as my previous job position?

Tags: salary

So I work in a Factory & I normally work in **General Assembly for 10.25$ an hour on 2nd shift.

Recently our supervisor has been sending people to work in a much much harder and stressful part of the building.

People that were hired in for that part of the building are working for 12$ an hour or more!

I am still only getting 10.25$ and hour for working  in that part of the building.

A friend of mine has been consecutively over there for 4 days and even had to work 1 weekend day. He is royaly pissed and is stressed to the max.

Is there anything I can do to get them to stop?
Maybe a temporary raise for when I am over in the harder section of the building?
It is really getting to me and it seems majorly unfair.

Comment: Your question seems like a rant. If you can calm down enough to provide more context, such as what country you're in, what your employment contract/agreement says, someone may have some meaningful advice to give you. In general, the answer to, "Can they do this?" is, "Yes, they can."

Comment: Didn't even think to add a country. It is in the US.

I'm assuming I can't do much.
If it keeps up I will look for another job.

Comment: Yes it's okay, and it's okay for you to find a better position in a different company.

Comment: 4 days seems a little over the top to use the term "constantly"

Answer (score 3):

Is the factory unionized? If so, talk to your union representatives.

Otherwise: Unless you are willing to quit or be fired over it, there isn't much you can do. Almost every employment contract includes "other duties as assigned."

In a sane workplace, these *might* be try-out's to see who should be promoted to the higher-paid position. That's another reason you may or may not want to hesitate before protesting too strongly.

I think I'd start by asking management what's up -- is this temporary or longer term, how could you get assigned there more permanently and get the higher pay or how you could limit the time spent there at your current pay... Decide what you want, and talk to management about whether you can make it happen or get some other recognition for extra effort.

Re working weekends: See past answers. If your contract doesn't require it, you don't have to work overtime... but they don't have to continue employing you either. Be careful where and when you draw lines.

Comment: It is not, sadly.
I'm totally fine in the area I am in and the pay. I can survive off the pay given the hours I am working and the decent overtime.
The area they had me in has people quitting all the time because of the strenuous work involved. The pay isn't very good for what they make people do either. Even at 12$ an hour.

To be quite honest, if it keeps happening and puts a toll on my mental and physical well-being I will have to look for another job.

Comment: @Sobun That is a good thing to say to your manager.  "I'm totally fine in the area I am in and the pay.  The other area has people quitting all the time because of the strenuous work even at $12 an hour. To be quite honest, if it keeps happening and puts a toll on my mental and physical well-being I will have to look for another job."  An employer with a brain between their ears will look at the short term gain of filling those shoes today versus the long run loss of losing you as an employee.